# Why global variables are not known at compile-time?

Tags: c++, global-variables, constexpr, constant-expression

In C++, I know that if a I declared a variable inside a function, this variable is actually considered as `auto` local variable (destroyed once a function does `return`). So it stands to reason that, a local variable cannot appears in a constant expression like an initializer for a `constexpr` variable, because simply it known at runtime, it needs the function in which it declared to be executed and that's happening only at runtime.

```
int x { 10 };
constexpr int y { x }; //error: x should be const

int main()
{
    //..
}
```

My question is, what would happen if this variable is global? So no runtime functions need to be executed in order to know the value of `x`, because it does not belong to any functions? My question, in other words, when does exactly the compiler knows the value of this variable `x`

I already know that, if the variable `x` is const, then `x` will be a constant expression but why is that?

Answer (score 2):

In your particular example, the compiler can possibly know. It just doesn't have to.

But what if you have

```
int x { 10 };
someclass trix{};
constexpr int y { x }; //error: x should be const
```

Now the constructor for `trix` just *could*  modify `x`, and the compiler wouldn't know. Especially if trix.cpp is compiled after the main file.